# Limit JOIN to 1 result (latest) MySQL

Tags: mysql

I imagine I have done something daft here but I just can't see it.

I have 2 tables I am trying to join in a query. One contains incidents and the other audit data for showing when an incident is updated. I would like to be able to select the data in the incidents table, and a timestamp for the latest audit entry; so I can show a 'last updated' column.

See abridged tables below:

**incedententry:**

| IncidentID | IncidentRef | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | i-abc123 | ... |

**incidentaudit:**

| AuditID | IncidentRef | *** | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | i-abc123 | *** | 2022-01-20 11:30:00 |
| 2 | i-abc123 | *** | 2022-01-20 12:00:00 |

This is the query I have created. I have attempted to *JOIN* the incidentaudit table using a subquery with a limit of 1. This does not seem to work though. The returned result has a row for each audit entry...

**Query:**

```
SELECT e.*,a.* FROM `incedententry` as `e` INNER JOIN `incidenttypes` ON `e`.`IncidentType` = `incidenttypes`.`IncidentTypeID` LEFT JOIN `incidentaudit` AS `a` ON `e`.`IncidentRef` = ( SELECT `IncidentRef` FROM `incidentaudit` AS `a2` WHERE `a2`.`IncidentRef` = `e`.`IncidentRef` ORDER BY `a`.`TimeStamp` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

**Result**

| IncidentID | IncidentRef | ... | AuditID | IncidentRef | *** | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | i-abc123 | ... | 1 | i-abc123 | *** | 2022-01-20 11:30:00 |
| 55 | i-abc123 | ... | 2 | i-abc123 | *** | 2022-01-20 12:00:00 |

The desired result would be:

| IncidentID | IncidentRef | ... | AuditID | IncidentRef | *** | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | i-abc123 | ... | 2 | i-abc123 | *** | 2022-01-20 12:00:00 |

*Thank you in advance for any assistance!*

Comment: Select maximal timestamp per incident in subquery, use this value for rows selection.

Comment: @Akina Smashing, thank you.

Comment: @Akina I thought I had it with SELECT e.*,a.* FROM `incedententry` as `e` INNER JOIN `incidenttypes` ON `e`.`IncidentType` = `incidenttypes`.`IncidentTypeID` LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(`TIMESTAMP`),`IncidentRef` FROM `incidentaudit`) AS `a` ON e.`IncidentRef` = `a`.`IncidentRef` but that only returns the max timestamp for the first row. Multiple incidents comeback with NULL for the timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*, a.* 
FROM incedententry as e 
INNER JOIN incidenttypes 
  ON e.IncidentType = incidenttypes.IncidentTypeID 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp, IncidentRef 
  FROM incidentaudit 
  GROUP BY IncidentRef -- you were missing this
) AS a 
  ON e.IncidentRef = a.IncidentRef;
```